# Count item checked on Checkboxbar Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: checkbox, wolfram-mathematica

I have a `Checkboxbar` like this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
{CheckboxBar[{1, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]}
```

I would like to count how much items are selected, and have an action for example when 2 item are selected. How can i do that? I have no idea. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Dynamic` documentation page about the usage of the second argument of it.

```
items = {1};

CheckboxBar[
 Dynamic[items, (items = #; If[Length@items == 2, Print["two items"]]) &],
 Range@5
]
```